# Phonegap's Insomnia Plugin not working

Tags: android, plugins, phonegap-plugins

I am using this plugin:
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin

with Phonegap to prevent the Android screen from falling asleep.

To prevent sleeping: window.plugins.insomnia.keepAwake();
And to allow sleeping again:  window.plugins.insomnia.allowSleepAgain();

Thing is, it works for me, but it does not work on my customer's Android phone. His screen goes blank after a while.

Is there a version of Android that does not work with this plugin?